# How i can steering cube in Unity for android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'am got steering for keybord "a" to left and "d" for right, but how i can change this code for steering win android? Iam mean if i click on the left side of the screen my cube going to left and also when i click on the right side of the screen my cube will go to right side?

```
 void FixedUpdate () {
    rb.AddForce (0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKey ("d")) {
        rb.AddForce (sidewaysRight * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    } else if (Input.GetKey ("a")) {
        rb.AddForce (sidewaysLeft * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to implement this is to add an `Overlay Canvas` to your scene and place two transparent Images in each side, each covering the area that should activate the respective steering direction.

Then add the `EventTrigger` component to each one and add the `PointerEnter` and `PointerExit` events.

On your main script you'll want to declare the methods that will execute when the events are fired. For example:

```
bool steeringLeft, steeringRight;

public void OnLeftPointerEnter(BaseEventData data)
{
    steeringLeft = true;
}

public void OnLeftPointerExit(BaseEventData data)
{
    steeringLeft = false;
}

public void OnRightPointerEnter(BaseEventData data)
{
    steeringRight = true;
}

public void OnRightPointerExit(BaseEventData data)
{
    steeringRight = false;
}
```

Finally, link these methods to the events in the EventTriggers and you're good to go:

```
void FixedUpdate () 
{
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

    if (steeringRight)
        rb.AddForce (sidewaysRight * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    else if (steeringLeft)
        rb.AddForce (sidewaysLeft * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

NOTE: However, I do believe it would be cooler to implement the steering with the smartphone's gyroscope :)